# How to use bootstrap datepicker's toDisplay function?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to make the bootstrap datepicker display the date in UTC instead of in the browser timezone (as it does by default). I read in the docs that I can specify toDisplay and toValue functions and make them customize how the display is done. As I was implementing the toDisplay function, I first set the date in the element like this:

```
divElement.datepicker('update', new Date(1420066800000));
```

Then I was debugging toDisplay() and the first step was to check the value of the first parameter of the toDisplay() function, which is a date object, and make sure it has the same value I supplied when setting the date using 'update', but I noticed that it's different and so my question is why is that so?

The value I supplied when using 'update' is 1420066800000 which is printed as "Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)" and the value of the date parameter of toDisplay() is printed as "Thu Jan 01 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)".

Thanks.